# Is var variable different from this in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, this, javascript-objects, var

I have a bit of a confusion on the term `var` and declaring a variable with keyword `this` in a JavaScript constructor function. For example, in the code below, is `var title` a different variable than `happySongs[0].title`. They are both initialized with something different. title is initialized in the constructor to song parameter and title is also initialized outside the constructor function. However, they both return something different. If you print out `happySongs[0].title` it gives you the new value. However, if you print out the `concat()` method, title will not have the new value of 'test', but rather the old one.... So there are two different things going on here? Are these separate variables? Is there a difference when you declare a variable with `var` and `this` inside a function constructor?

```
function Tune(song,artist) {
  var title = song;
  this.concat = function() {
   return title + " " + artist;
 }
}

var happySongs = [];
happySongs[0] = new Tune("Putting on the Ritz", "Ella Fitzgerald");

happySongs[0].title = 'test'
//prints out test
console.log(happySongs[0].title); 

 // prints out correct title and artist
console.log(happySongs[0].concat());
```

Comment: `var x` declares a variable, `this.x` is a property of the object. They're completely different.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do JavaScript closures work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Comment: yes, there is a difference which you have already demonstrated

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/310870/use-of-prototype-vs-this-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are different.

```
var title = song;
```

Is a *locally scoped* variable within the constructor function.

```
happySongs[0].title = 'test'
```

Is creating a `title` *property* on the constructed `Tune` object.  Changing one will have no affect on the other.  The `concat` function, being declared within the constructor function, has access to the locally scoped `title` variable declared in the outer scope.  If you reference `this.title` instead, you would get the property:

```
this.concat = function() {
  return this.title + " " + artist;
}
```

The above, if placed in your original code, would cause the final line:

```
console.log(happySongs[0].concat());
```

To output `"test Ella Fitzgerald"`.

Answer (score 0):

`var title` is a local variable. `this.concat = function()` then "closes" over the title/artist variables. `this.title` and `[0].title` are properties of the object.

Answer (score 0):

> is "var title" a different variable than "happySongs[0].title"

Yes, they are different variables. The reason for the confusion, I think, is on the line

```
happySongs[0].title = 'test'
```

Before that line is executed, happySongs[0] does not have a public "title" property.

When you declared `var title = song` from within the "constructor", you created a locally scoped variable. The tricky part is that, when you created the concat function, JavaScript creates what's called a "closure". A closure is basically a grouping of a function and it's environment. In order for concat to run, it needs to know what the variable "title" has. So whenever concat is called, it looks at that variable. It doesn't matter when the function is called, it will always look at that local variable. Even if it's technically "out of scope".

After calling `happySongs[0].title = 'test'`, you've created an actual public property on that object named "test". This property can be accessed from outside of the object whenever you want, but it won't change the concat function because the concat function is in it's own closure (looking at the local title variable). Note that, if you made the concat function like

```
return this.title + " " + artist;
```

with the "this" keyword, then the concat function would look at the public property on the object (which you'd be able to change at a later time).

You can think of the `var title = song;` line as creating a "private" property. It's only accessible from within the object. This is definitely a simplified way of looking at it. If you want to understand more about what's happening, you have to understand JavaScript scoping and closures.

http://robertnyman.com/2008/10/09/explaining-javascript-scope-and-closures/